# JavaFX correct way to call statge.show() and mediaPlayer.play()

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to show notification on right corner of windows, in which I am playing animation and sound. Below code is working perfectly when I am starting Test.main() for first time, but when I am trying to play same animation and sound it not working. Please help me.. thanks in advance

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NotificationRunnable(), 0, 2 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NotificationRunnable(), 0, 4 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NotificationRunnable(), 0, 9 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NotificationRunnable(), 0, 13 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       
        //Launching application first time
        NotificationApp.runFromScheduledExecutor();
        
    }

}
```

NotificationRunnable.java

```
public class NotificationRunnable implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            NotificationApp.playAnimation();
        });
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}

Notification.java

public class NotificationApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    static Stage primaryStage = null;
    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create a custom dialog with an ImageView
        Image gifImage = new Image(String.valueOf(new File("img/giphy.gif"))); // Replace with your GIF file path
        ImageView gifImageView = new ImageView(gifImage);
        Pane pane = new Pane(gifImageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        // Set stage properties
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT); // Hide the window decoration
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        // Determine screen dimensions
        double screenWidth = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth();
        double screenHeight = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight();
        double stageWidth = gifImage.getWidth();
        double stageHeight = gifImage.getHeight();

        // Set the stage position to the right corner
        double xOffset = screenWidth - stageWidth;
        double yOffset = screenHeight - stageHeight;
        primaryStage.setX(xOffset);
        primaryStage.setY(yOffset);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        Media sound = new Media(new Test().getClass().getResource("/snd/Notification.mp3").toExternalForm());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
        //Play animation and Sound during application start
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            playAnimation();
        });
    }

    public static void playAnimation(){
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            mediaPlayer.play();
            primaryStage.show();
        });
        // Schedule closing the stage after 5 seconds
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.schedule(() -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                primaryStage.close();
            });
        }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    public static void runFromScheduledExecutor() {
        Application.launch(NotificationApp.class);
    }

}
```

I am trying to play animation and sound from Runnable by calling playAnimation(). but this code is not playing animation, when I launch the application for first time it play animation and sound as per requirment but not working for second time.

Comment: I did not look deeply at your code, but I am not sure why you would need a `Runnabler` to play animations or sounds. I would suggest looking into JavaFX's `Animation` `API`.

Comment: If you want to play a sound, maybe an AudioClip is better than a MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove all use of `static` fields, and I would remove all uses of ScheduledExecutorService.

I realize that the static fields were necessary since the `main` method of Test has no way to access the instance of NotificationApp created by JavaFX, but the better way to do this is to have only one main method, so you won’t need to worry about accessing a NotificationApp instance from other classes.

If you want to make NotificationApp capable of performing different actions, use its [command line arguments](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters()).  Instead of ScheduledExecutorService.schedule, use the [setOnFinished](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished(javafx.event.EventHandler)) method of [PauseTransition](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html), which will remove the need for Platform.runLater there.  Instead of ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate, create a [Timeline with a single KeyFrame](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.animation.KeyFrame...)) whose listener performs the task.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.Screen;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

import javafx.util.Duration;

public class NotificationApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    // Schedule closing the stage after 5 seconds
    private Animation closer;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create a custom dialog with an ImageView
        Image gifImage = new Image(String.valueOf(new File("img/giphy.gif"))); // Replace with your GIF file path
        ImageView gifImageView = new ImageView(gifImage);
        Pane pane = new Pane(gifImageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        // Set stage properties
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT); // Hide the window decoration
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        // Determine screen dimensions
        double screenWidth = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth();
        double screenHeight = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight();
        double stageWidth = gifImage.getWidth();
        double stageHeight = gifImage.getHeight();

        // Set the stage position to the right corner
        double xOffset = screenWidth - stageWidth;
        double yOffset = screenHeight - stageHeight;
        primaryStage.setX(xOffset);
        primaryStage.setY(yOffset);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        Media sound = new Media(NotificationApp.class.getResource("/snd/Notification.mp3").toExternalForm());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);

        closer = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
        closer.setOnFinished(e -> {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            primaryStage.close();
        });

        List<String> args = getParameters().getRaw();
        if (args.isEmpty()) {
            //Play animation and Sound during application start
            Platform.runLater(() -> playAnimation());
        } else {
            Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
            for (String arg : args) {
                Duration interval = Duration.valueOf(arg);
                Timeline repeater = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(interval, e -> playAnimation()));
                repeater.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                repeater.play();
            }
        }
    }

    private void playAnimation() {
        mediaPlayer.play();
        primaryStage.show();

        closer.playFromStart();
    }

}
```

The event handlers of PauseTransition and Timeline are called in the JavaFX application thread, so there is no need for Platform.runLater.

The application can be invoked like this:

```
java -p /opt/java/javafx/lib --add-modules javafx.graphics,javafx.media NotificationApp 2m 4m 9m 13m
```

The meaning of arguments like `2m` is explained in [the documentation of Duration.valueOf](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/util/Duration.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).  Note that this is the javafx.util.Duration class, not java.time.Duration.

**Caution:** Using an interval of 2 minutes already guarantees the notification will be shown every 4 minutes.  Specifying both 2 minutes *and* 4 minutes means that every 4 minutes, **two notifications** will be displayed at the same time, on top of each other.  And, as you might imagine, specifying both 2 minutes and 9 minutes means two simultaneous notifications will appear every 18 minutes.  Specifying both 2 minutes and 13 minutes means two simultaneous notifications will appear every 26 minutes.

You probably should only specify a single interval, like `2m`, when testing.